# Validar Select jqueryValidate com Materializecss

Tags: jquery, materialize

Encontrei um problema que não estou conseguindo solução a um tempinho, estou trabalhando com o framework [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/). Ele possui validação com algumas notações diretas na tag HTML, o que não estou conseguindo é validar é quando tenho uma tag `select`.

Segue o código:

```
<div class="input-field col s1">
    <select id="comboBasculante" name="comboBasculante">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
        <option value="1">Basculante</option>
        <option value="2">Fixo</option>
        <option value="3">Janela</option>
        <option value="4">Porta</option>
        <option value="4">Stanley</option>
    </select>
    <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="comboBasculante">Produto</label>
</div>
```

Comment: O que acontece?

Answer (score 1):

O [material_select](https://materializecss.com/select.html) faz o seu do select um `display: none` e o [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) ignora campos campos ocultos. Para ativar a validação de campos ocultos use:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
  ignore: []
});
```

Ps.: Use no seu select o atributo `required`

```js
$('select').material_select();

$.validator.setDefaults({
  ignore: []
});

$("form").validate({
  errorClass: "invalid form-error",
  errorElement: 'div',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parent());
  }
});
```

```css
.form-error {
  color: #D8000C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form>
  <select required>
    <option value="">- Selecione -</option>
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta esse código. Eu acrescentei a tag `required`do html 5 e tirei o valor do placeholder.

```
<div class="input-field col s1">
<select id="comboBasculante" name="comboBasculante" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Basculante</option>
    <option value="2">Fixo</option>
    <option value="3">Janela</option>
    <option value="4">Porta</option>
    <option value="4">Stanley</option>
</select>
<label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="comboBasculante">Produto</label>
```

Você pode checar nessa documentação: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element

Answer (score 0):

Adicione a instância do Materialize,como recomendado na documentação:
[Documentação do Materialize](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select-initialization).

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').material_select();
    });
```

```css
*{
background:#f1f1f1;
}
.mySelect{
margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            
        <script type="text/javascript">
  
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select').material_select();
        });
       
        </script>
        <div class="container">
      <div class="input-field col s1">
<select id="comboBasculante" name="comboBasculante" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
<option value="1">Basculante</option>
<option value="2">Fixo</option>
<option value="3">Janela</option>
<option value="4">Porta</option>
<option value="4">Stanley</option>
</select>
<label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="comboBasculante">Produto</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solução Definitiva:**

O MATCSS cria um `<input>` para substituir o `<select>`, mas não passa os parâmetros de validação para este input, como a classe `validate` e o span com `helper-text`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect(); 
    const _requiredSelects = $("select[required].validate");
    _requiredSelects.parent().find('input').addClass('validate').attr('required', true)
    .keydown(function($event) { 
        return $event.keyCode == 9;
    });
    _requiredSelects.change(function($event) { 
        const _select = $event.target;
        const _value = $(_select).val();
        const _input = $(_select).parent().find('input');
        _input.removeAttr('readonly', '');
        _input.val(_select.options[_select.options.selectedIndex].label);
        if (_value != '') {
            _input.addClass('valid');
            _input.removeClass('invalid');
        } else {
            _input.addClass('invalid');
            _input.removeClass('valid');
        }
    });
    _requiredSelects.each(function(){
        const _this = $(this);
        const _helper = _this.parent().parent().find('.helper-text');
        if (_helper !== undefined) {
            const _input = _this.parent().find('input');
            _helper.insertAfter(_input);
        }
    });
});
```